# Windows 8 cannot shut down, hibernate or sleep. It can only restart

Tags: windows-8, boot, shutdown, reboot, bcd

Hoping to get lucky as i've tried to fix this problem for months.

I was using my PC to fix the BCD of another. I accidentally altered my own boot records which got me in a bit of strife. After many rebuilds of the BCD and manual edits it finally started booting again.

However, it is never able to shut down fully. The applications close and I get the dotted ring but it stops just before the hardware shuts down. Fan is running and screen is black but not off. Hibernate exhibits the same behaviour but after a forced shutdown and restart it does actually resume the hibernation session correctly. Strange, huh?

Regards restart vs shut down, the MS Blog has this to say:

> From a cmd prompt, run: `shutdown /s /full / t 0` to invoke an immediate full shutdown.

Also, choosing Restart from the UI will do a full shutdown, followed by a cold boot.

There must be some nuance here as I can restart 100% fine.

As I was messing with the boot records, I suspect it is due to something there, but all my google-fu hasn't been able to come up with any possible resolutions.

Cheers

Comment: It sounds like the motherboard isn't telling the power supply to cut power, which means the OS isn't telling the motherboard to shut down properly.  That's not needed for a restart, which is why that works fine.  Perhaps try rebuilding your MBR, although I'm not sure how to do that in Windows 8.

Comment: Ah! Great suggestion!!

Comment: Actually my computer doesn't have an MBR. It has UEFI instead. Any ideas?

Comment: It is probably not because of the BCD.  All that does it launch Windows.  Check out your power settings.  Often Win8.1 will not hibernate.  But it should restart correctly, and should be able to sleep.  It sounds like you did a lot of work on it so probably wouldn't hurt to go back and review all the settings to make sure they are the way you want them.

Comment: did you try opening device manager and reinstall the power devices' drivers?